# sql.Named argument in GORM to build clauses

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am using GORM to query a database as such:

```
query := `
    SELECT *
    ...
    ORDER BY col @colOrder`
result := DB.Raw(
    query,
    sql.Named("colOrder", "ASC"),
)
```

I am getting a syntax error from the database because the `sql.Named` converts "ASC" to a string as such:

```
SELECT *
...
ORDER BY col 'ASC'
```

How can I get GORM to interpret it as such:

```
SELECT * 
...
ORDER BY col ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Order) the custom ordering could done like this:

```golang
query := `
    SELECT *
    ...
    FROM table`
result := DB.Raw(query).Order("col ASC")
```

Answer (score 0):

The named arguments are for passing actual data to the query, hence it will quote strings and lead to your error.

For passing bits of the query itself you can just modify the string with the normal string processing facilities of go (`fmt.Sprintf`, `strings.Replace`, etc.) *as long as those strings do not come directly from user input*, or you risk SQL injection vulnerabilities.

**DON'T DO**:

```golang
order := request.Query().Get("order")
query := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT ... ORDER BY col %s`, order)
```

**CAN DO**:

```golang
order := "ASC"
if request.Query().Get("order") == "desc" {
    order = "DESC"
}
query := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT ... ORDER BY col %s`, order)
```

You can also do the same with the `Order` function when using the query builder:

```golang
query := db.Model(...).
    ...
    Order(fmt.Sprintf("col %s", order)).
    Find(...)
```